# Create a dll dynamic library from C in R (Windows)

Tags: c, r, dll

I want to create a dll dynamic library from a C source code so that I can load and use it in R. I am now using

```
R CMD SHLIB foo.c
```

in Windows 7 command line. But nothing happened. There is no error message but no dll file was created.

What's wrong with what I have done? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am sorry if my question is not very clear. But I figured it out how to get things work and possible mistakes. Hopefully it will be useful for someone. Here are the steps:

1. Install R (latest version is 3.0.0 now). Make sure to add R bin folder to PATH
2. Install the latest version of Rtools [Here](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/). Make sure to add "c:\Rtools\bin;c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;" to PATH
3. Write your C code, saved in foo.c
4. In Windows command window, type

   R CMD SHLIB foo.c

then you should have a foo.dll file then you can call it in R. Note that the foo.dll created under 64bits R can only be loaded into 64bits R. If you try to load in 32bits R, you will get error messages.

Comment: You can also try: [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/), [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), [msysGit](https://msysgit.github.io/) (netinstall only), but Rtools works better!

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what do you mean by "nothing happened"?  Is R in your path?

What does `R --version` reveal?  How about `R CMD config CC` and `R CMD config CFLAGS`?

Lastly, if you had Rcpp installed (and your toolchain was correct, including PATH settings and all the rest) the you could do things on the fly a la

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> cppFunction('double foo(double x) { return std::sqrt(x); }')
R> foo(4)
[1] 2
R> foo(4.2)
[1] 2.04939
R> unclass(foo)
function (x) 
.Primitive(".Call")(<pointer: 0x7f251ba76530>, x)
R>
```

Here we used `cppFunction()` (and a bunch of tricks inside Rcpp) to compile, link and load
a simple (and pretty useless...) C(++) function which takes a square root.